# What are the webresource.xsd and scriptresource.xsd files

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

What are the webresource.xsd and scriptresource.xsd files and where are they found?

I am asking in relation to asp.net mvc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They act like datasources especially when you need to generate some reports for your application.